# Required field Missing 35 on NewOrderSingle Market Order

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

Don't know why the the FIX server is throwing this error. Using Fix.4.4, I've got a client generating a Market Order. Its being received by the Server, but its returning an error.

The Logon is successful on the client and server side. Then the client sends a market order:

```
Header [8=FIX.4.4 | 9=130 | 35=D | 34=92 | 49=BROKER_CLIENT | 52=20121009-00:58:44.283 | 56=BROKER_SERVER | ] Body [11=0 | 21=1 | 38=100 | 40=1 | 54=1 | 55=JNJ | 59=0 | 60=20121009-00:58:44 | ] Trailer [10=035 | ]
```

This is received from the 'fromApp' method of the server. The server then responds with:
 (Message 92 Rejected: Conditionally Required Field Missing:35)

Field35 is clearly there, can't see why the server is responding with an error.

Comment: Post the FIX message the server receives and also the one you send. Not the message from the logs, log it in the toApp. And paste the full reject message.

Answer (score 0):

This question was also posted to the mailing list.  Turns out Mr. Flores was calling

```
std::string msgType = message.getField(FIX::FIELD::MsgType);
```

instead of

```
std::string msgType = message.getHeader().getField(FIX::FIELD::MsgType);
```

in his `FromApp()` call.